# jqgrid multiple search

Tags: search, jqgrid

I'm new to jqGrid. I'm trying to implement multiple search. As far as I can see, jqGrid can generate a string that I can put in the WHERE clause of my SQL statement for the search to take place. I can see that generated string when I specify

```
showQuery: true
```

in the search options. However I don't know how can I send this string to my php script on server. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to use the string which you see in case of the `showQuery:true` option. Instead of that you should deserialize the [filters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options) on the server side and then construct the SELECT statement in your code.

If you use ASP.NET and Entity Framework you will find the solution in the UPDATED part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644). If you need construct the SQL SELECT statement dynamically and you don't use .NET you should take in the consideration SQL injection problem. So you should use parameters in the SQL statements chich you will construct.